# Can't parse certain fields from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I've written a script in python with selenium to grab the `Director` name and `Phone` number from a webpage. When I execute my script I get the results like below which are in a single list:

```
['Director: Cheryl Hughley\nPhone: 661-421-5861\nEmail: Cheryl_hughley@yahoo.com']
```

How can I parse only the name and the phone number ***on the fly*** from that site in separate fields like:

```
name: Cheryl Hughley
phone : 661-421-5861
```

This is what I tried that produces the result within a list (first example) above:

```
from selenium import webdriver

link ="https://www.nafe.com/bakersfield-nafe-network"

def search_info(driver,url):
    driver.get(url)
    info = [item.text.strip() for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".markdown p") if "Phone" in item.text]

    print(f'{info}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    try:
        search_info(driver,link)
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```

I do not wish to process the result after they are parsed; rather, I wish to get them on the fly. Will regex be a good option here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below solution:

```
info = [driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].childNodes[arguments[1]].textContent;", item, index).strip() for index in [0, 2] for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".markdown p") if "Phone" in item.text]
```

to get output

```
['Director: Cheryl Hughley', 'Phone:  661-421-5861']
```

or

```
info = [driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].childNodes[arguments[1]].textContent;", item, index).split(": ")[-1].strip() for index in [0, 2] for item in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".markdown p") if "Phone" in item.text]
```

to get

```
['Cheryl Hughley', '661-421-5861']
```

Comment: It seems it will be a little hard for me to understand what you did, sir. A oneliner explanation on how it worked would be very helpful.

Comment: `text` property returns you the whole text content of node. To get separate child text nodes you need to use javaScript `"return webElement.childNodes[textNodeIndex].textContent;"`. `arguments[0]` and `arguments[1]` are just the placeholders for `driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".markdown p")` and text node index (`0` is index of `'Director: Cheryl Hughley'`, `2` is index of `'Phone:  661-421-5861'`) appropriately